# Steam Web API Getting game list of user with no steam profile

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

I have searched forums and I found sample pattern for getting all games of user like this: 
http://steamcommunity.com/id//games?tab=all&xml=1 returns all games. However if an user didn't set up steam profiles already, even though he/she have game, they don't comes in this above url.
(e.g) http://steamcommunity.com/id/76561198061133470/games?tab=all&xml=1

I have Steam Web API Key. I want to get the games list. Can anybody point a method/call for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to work if you use "profiles" instead of "id"

With your exemple : http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198061133470/games?tab=all&xml=1

Comment: Really Awesome, I don't see this feature is documented. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: @Jones it is documented, here: https://partner.steamgames.com/documentation/community_data

Answer (score 4):

If it is a customUrl then use the

`http://steamcommunity.com/id/<custom>`

else use the

`http://steamcommunity.com/profile/<steamid>`

you can use any of the steamcommunity url to retrieve data by adding `?xml=1` to the end of the url